# How to alter font color when a dropdown changes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the color of the text in a dropdown box. Urgent, Important and Normal. Urgent should be red, Important orange and Normal is green. I created the following JavaScript but the other alert does not work beside the sample alert. The color doesn't change either.

```
        var d = NWF$('#' + jsPriority + ' option:selected').val();
       //alert(d);
        switch (d)
  {
            case("Urgent - Immediate Attention or Response Required within 2 days"):
                 alert(d);
                 //$(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
                 NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
                 break;
            //case d.startsWith("Urgent"):            
            //break;
            case ("Important - High Attention or Response Required within 7 days"): 
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find('option:selected').css('color', 'orange');                
                break;
            case ("Normal - Review or Response Required within 14 days"): 
                //alert(d);
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find('option:selected').css('color', 'green');
                break;            
        }
```

Comment: is there a console error?

Comment: I updated the code see OP and I dont see any error.

Comment: It's not clear what you are having problems with: capturing the control change event or doing the colour change itself. If it's just the colour change, the title perhaps could do with another edit. (Aside: we like [titles to be in plain English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495) here, rather than a collection of symbol-separated tags).

Comment: What's the HTML for the select tag in question, I think it may have something to do with your value attributes on the options, but cannot confirm without the `<select>` tag

Comment: Looks like some clarification questions have gone unanswered, so voting to close. A question that is unclear is not useful to future readers, even if it has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work. Here is the working version of the jquery code.

```
// coloring priority
NWF$(document).ready(function() {    
        var d = NWF$('#' + jsPriority + ' option:selected').val();
       //alert(d);
        switch (d)
  {
            case("Urgent - Immediate Attention or Response Required within 2 days"):
                 //alert(d);
                 //$(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
                 NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find(' option:selected').css('color', 'red');
                 NWF$('#'+jsPriority).css('color', 'red');
                 break;
            //case d.startsWith("Urgent"):            
            //break;
            case ("Important - High Attention or Response Required within 7 days"): 
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find(' option:selected').css('color', 'orange'); 
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).css('color', 'orange');               
                break;
            case ("Normal - Review or Response Required within 14 days"): 
                //alert(d);
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find(' option:selected').css('color', 'green');
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).css('color', 'green');
                break;            
        }   
});


// coloring priority
NWF$(document).ready(function() {    
NWF$('#' + jsPriority).change(function() {
        var d = NWF$('#' + jsPriority + ' option:selected').val();
       //alert(d);
        switch (d)
  {
            case("Urgent - Immediate Attention or Response Required within 2 days"):
                 //alert(d);
                 //$(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
                 NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find(' option:selected').css('color', 'red');
                 NWF$('#'+jsPriority).css('color', 'red');
                 break;
            //case d.startsWith("Urgent"):            
            //break;
            case ("Important - High Attention or Response Required within 7 days"): 
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find(' option:selected').css('color', 'orange'); 
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).css('color', 'orange');               
                break;
            case ("Normal - Review or Response Required within 14 days"): 
                //alert(d);
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).find(' option:selected').css('color', 'green');
                NWF$('#'+jsPriority).css('color', 'green');
                break;            
        }   
});
});
```